# Load different JS library files for different components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-scripts, script-tag, hamlet

I have a website made in ReactJS. In `public/index.html`, I have

```
<head>
  <script src="/lib/analyzejs-v1.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/analyzejs-v2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

where `analyzejs-v1.js` has 6Mo, and `analyzejs-v2.js` has 3Mo; they are all fixed files that I could not much modify.

These two files are not modules; their functions are declared (e.g., `declare function f1(address: string): string;` in `src/defines/analyzejs-v1.d.ts`). So some components call functions of `analyzejs-v1.js` by using a function name like `f1(...)` directly without any namespace, import, or export. And the rest of the components call functions of `analyzejs-v2.js` by using a function name like `f2(...)` directly without any namespace, import, or export.

It takes time to load these two js library files. So I'm looking for a way to load either `analyzejs-v1.js` or `analyzejs-v2.js` according to the component (or URL).

So does anyone know a conventional way to load different JS library files for different components?

Comment: What is compiling / bundling your `index.tsx`?

Comment: I guess it is `webpack`

Comment: Do you want `webpack` to bundle the analyze js file or are you manually including it with your script tags in head?

Comment: At the moment, I just manually copy the analyze js file to where it is needed. I don't have any preference, I'm looking for a conventional way.

Comment: is the analyze file part of source code? I'm guessing it was generated if it's super big.

Comment: the analyze file is a library file generated by something else, you could consider it can be separated from the react frontend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238372/discussion-between-programmerraj-and-softtimur).

Comment: did you try lazy loading creating some chunks to load for your components? https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need two script at the same time, you can add the script tag in the runtime when necessary.
I can provide you a hook which I have used to load the script on the fly.

```
export function useScript(url: string, clean: boolean = false, cleanJob: () => void = () => undefined): boolean {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    let create = false;
    let script = document.querySelector(`script[src="${url}"]`) as HTMLScriptElement | null;
    if (!script) {
      script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = url;
      script.async = true;
      if (type (document as any).attachEvent === 'object') {
        (script as any).onreadystatechange = () => {
          if ((script as any).readyState === 'loaded') {
            setLoaded(true);
          }
        }
      } else {
        script.onload = () => {
          setLoaded(true);
        }
      }
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      create = true;
    } else {
      setLoaded(true);
    }
    // For a special library, you can do the clean work by deleting the variable it exports.
    return () => {
      if (create && script && clean) {
        setLoaded(false);
        document.body.removeChild(script);
        cleanJob && cleanJob();
      }
    }
  }, [url]);
  return loaded;
}
```

To use it:

```
export const Comp = (props: ICompProps) => {
 const loaded = useScript('https://path/to/the/script.js');
 // if you want to do some clean work, Suppose the external script introduces the variable A, And A can be reasigned.
 // const loaded = useScript('https://path/to/the/script.js', true, () -> { A = undefined; });
 useEffect(() -> {
   if (loaded) {
     // Suppose the external script introduces the variable A. Now it is available.
     const a = new A();
     // do something with a.
   }
 }, [loaded]);
 if (loaded) {
   return XXX;  
 } else {
   return null;
 }
}
```

If the script is not a module, just add a typescript declare file without import statements, and declare the global variable the script export. Such as:

```
declare interface XXX {
  YYY
}
declare const ScriptValue: XXX;
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me more about how to call `useScript` in a component?

Comment: `type (document as any)` should be `typeof (document as any)`?

Comment: using `script as any` is because that its the ie8 case.  `attachEvent` is not the attribute of document in ts option.  I will edit the answer to add the use case

Comment: `type (document as any) should be typeof (document as any)?` Yes

Answer (score 1):

When you import a script using the `<script>` tag, the library can only be used client side and therefore not with node. However, if you mark it as a module, another script can use it like this:

index.html:

```html
<script src="test.mjs" type="module"></script>
<script type="module">
      import {hello} from "./test.mjs"
      hello()
</script>
```

test.mjs:

```js
export function hello(text) {
    console.log("hello from test")
}
```

The only thing is the communication between your react scripts and that inline script. The only way, I figured out, how to achieve this is using `window`.

**DISCLAIMER**

I'm really not sure, if anyone should use it this way. I have only tested this once and it might very well break... Maybe someone else can tell me their opinion on my approach.

index.tsx

```js
... // imports

(window as any).importStuff = (a: any) => {
    a.hello()
}

...
```

index.html

```html
<script src="test.mjs" type="module"></script>
<script type="module">
      import {hello} from "./test.mjs"
      window.importStuff({
            hello: hello
      })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for better performance of the page and not let the scripts block the DOM content loading, then you may want to look at adding defer to the script https://javascript.info/script-async-defer#defer.

If you are looking for dynamic loading of script, and load the script only when its first used, check this doc https://javascript.info/script-async-defer#dynamic-scripts

Answer (score 1):

You can create `<script>` tag when your component is loaded.

At the first, We create a function to **create the script tag**

```js
const scriptGenerator = (options = {}) => {
    const s = document.createElement("script");
    for (const option in options) {
        s[option] = options[option]
    }

    document.querySelector("head").appendChild(s);
}
```

We can use **two attributes to load scripts**

- defer
- async

**`defer`:** The defer attribute tells the browser not to wait for the script. Instead, the browser will continue to process the HTML, build DOM. The script loads “in the background”, and then runs when the DOM is fully built.

**`async`:** The async attribute is somewhat like defer. It also makes the script non-blocking. But it has important differences in the behavior.

[async & defer Docs](https://javascript.info/script-async-defer)

**After all** these steps, we can **define** our **script** in the **head**. You can use `useEffect`

```js
useEffect(() => {
    // V1
    scriptGenerator({
        src: "...",
        async: 1,
    });

    // V2
    scriptGenerator({
        src: "...",
        async: 1,
    });
}, []);
```

Do not forget to **`delete` them after exiting** the component

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Generate script

    return () => {
        document
            .querySelector("head")
            .querySelectorAll('script[src="..."]')
            .remove();
    }
});
```

If we want to reach a conclusion, it is as **follows**:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
    const scriptGenerator = (options = {}) => {
        const s = document.createElement("script");
        for (const option in options) {
            s[option] = options[option]
        }

        document.querySelector("head").appendChild(s);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // V1
        scriptGenerator({
            src: "...",
            async: 1,
        });

        // V2
        scriptGenerator({
            src: "...",
            async: 1,
        });

        return () => {
            document
                .querySelector("head")
                .querySelectorAll('script[src="..."]')
                .remove();
        }
    });
}
```